# python lxml: Apply xslt over database records

Tags: python, sql, xslt, lxml

I'd like to use a xslt file and apply to database records instead of a xml file. It must be done in python.

For example suppose that the table in the database are:

```
TABLE topic
  id INTEGER
  title CHAR(200)
  body TEXT
  added DATETIME

TABLE comment
  topic_id REFERENCES(topic)
  body TEXT
  added DATETIME
```

Then i'd like the xslt to be processed like the xml was:

```
<topics>
  <topic>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>First topic</title>
    <body>Topic body</body>
    <added>11-12-2018 08:00:00</added>
  </topic>
  <topic>
     ...
  </topic>
</topics>
<comments>
  <comment>
    ...
  </comment>
</comments>
```

The problem with converting the database rows to xml is that the rows are really a lot (over 100M) and the xslt only uses a couple of them (on the order of 100) that vary between invocations.

I see that lxml is used a lot, and I was thinking about writing an alternative ElementTree class that fetches records from the database on-demand. Is that possible? Is it documented somewhere in the lxml documentation (I couldn't find it)?

Are there other ways to solve the problem (using xslt with database) using some other python package?

Comment: Please explain why you want to apply XSLT to database records. What is your goal?

Comment: I want to use XSLT as a convenient (and unified) way to get a structured output (that will then be rendered in many different ways according to the renderer) from the database without having to write explicit SQL.

Comment: I must add that there is no need for the xslt to order the dataset or to apply filters, since this is already done in the database itself using views.